# How can I cash US treasury check in India?

Tags: united-states, india, check, treasury

I have a United States Treasury check. Please let me know how to encash it in India. I tried ICICI bank but they are unable to process it.

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding, you only want to encash it?  It is possible deposit the money, but not encash it?

Comment: Do you have a bank account in India into which you could deposit the check, and the amount will be credited to your account a few weeks later when the check has made it back all the way to US? Or are you walking into ICICI as a non-customer and asking if they would give you cash in return for the check? Because of many reported problems with people filing fraudulent tax returns on behalf of other people (effectively identity theft) and getting refunds from the IRS/US Treasury, I wouldn't be surprised if even  _US_ banks would refuse to cash a US Treasury check for a non-customer.

Comment: ICICI bank refuses to entertain US treasury cheques inspite of having an bank account, anyone else had a similar exp, any other alternatives to get a US treasury cheque encashed in India

Comment: ICICI bank refuses to entertain US treasury cheques inspite of having an bank account, anyone else had a similar exp, any other alternatives to get a US treasury cheque encashed in India

Comment: Did any one succeed in processing a treasury check in India in any bank?

Answer (score 2):

You would require an account in ICICI, to process your Foreign currency cheque.

When you do have an account, these are the steps as mentioned on ICICI site:

*We accept cheques, travelers cheques, demand drafts, cashier orders, pay orders, and bankers' cheques etc*.

*Please submit your cheques along with a signed Indemnity Letter cum deposit slip to the nearest branch*.

*Please ensure that instruments are deposited at ICICI Branch in India with proper acknowledgment in the specified deposit slip only. Do not deposit instruments in drop boxes*.
Taken from this [link](http://www.icicibank.com/nri-banking/money_transfer/others/foreign_currency_cheque.page).

Comment: They are able to process other USD checks except treasury checks