# How to cash a cheque from the US in the U.K.?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, banking

I have been sent a cheque from the IRS in the United States and need to cash it in the UK, Lloyds bank have advised me they no longer provide this service. What are my alternatives?

Comment: See the answer to [this previous question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/71241/5760) for suggestions. Your wording might be a case of the US and UK being divided by a common language: cashing a check has a different meaning in the US (get cash back from a bank in exchange for a check) than cashing a cheque does in the UK (depositing a cheque into your account in a bank). See also [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/30634/5760) for how it does not work in a different country.

Answer (score 2):

I get regular USD dividend cheques from the USA (and an American bank) and have no problems [depositing them at Barclays](https://www.barclays.co.uk/help/payments/cheques/pay-foreign/) using a "Cheque Collection and Negotiation Formset".  No charge, other than Barclays lousy exchange rate.

Comment: US Treasury cheques can be treated differently by your bank from USD-denominated dividend cheques. Even in the US, a US Treasury cheque (usually an income-tax refund) payable to a married couple cannot be deposited into an account in the name of only one of the two; that is, it must be deposited into a _joint_ account on the name of the couple (and no one else, e.g. children).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.sapling.com/6831816/do-united-states-check-uk), you can either go to a foreign currency exchange shop, or visit a bank. It sounds like your bank doesn't offer this service, but that doesn't mean other banks also don't. Any major US bank (Wells Fargo, JP Morgan, etc.) should have branches in the UK, and you can visit them to see if you can cash the check.