# How do I safely transfer money from a US bank to a UK bank?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, money-transfer, international-transfer

I am currently living in the UK after many years in the US. I want to **safely** transfer some money from my US bank (Ally bank) to my bank account in the UK. (Ally Bank doesn't do international transfers, so I need to find another way of doing this.)

I had a bad experience doing this with Transferwise last year (I lost $200) and don't want to take any risks this time. Any thoughts on **safer ways of transferring the funds?** Are there any services that have a good reputation with regard to safety of funds/ integrity? **My priority with this transaction is safety with a bona fide company** and would prefer to pay more for wiring fees if this means I will get a better service/ peace of mind.

Comment: Unfortunately, product & service recommendations are off-topic.  Have you tried one of the Big Banks, like Chase?

Comment: Can your UK bank accept deposit of your US bank check? May take some time to clear and incur a fee but it's probably a "safer" way. See https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/85867/how-to-cash-a-cheque-from-the-us-in-the-u-k

Comment: $200 sounds like it could be either a big or small deal relative to the overall sum and exchange rate. The safest way to do it might be the one with the worst fees or exchange rate. A lot depends on the amount at stake.

Comment: What actually went wrong with Transferwise? Unexpected costs or did transferred money completely fail to arrive or be returned?

Comment: it's incredibly unlikely you "lost" $200 at transferwise.  if you don't like them, try ofx.com.  those are the only two large-scale companies in that field.